# Policy on syntax clarification questions

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons

Is there a policy, or a canonical thread on discussion policy, on syntax clarification questions?

[This question on an obscure piece of Ruby regex syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34022120/69755) is the motivation for this question. It asks about what `(?-mix:)` around a regular expression means. This isn't a very common piece of syntax, and if you [check the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html), it can be a little hard to find since it's buried in the text in a section that uses a different syntax for the main example of setting options, `/pat/i` etc.

I think that this question is perfectly reasonable to ask, since while it's just a pretty basic piece of syntax and is documented, it can be hard to find that documentation unless you know what you're looking for.

The question was closed as a duplicate of [a big FAQ type question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/69755); that is not a the same question, but is just a list of links to resources on various topics. In particular, to find the information on this feature in that answer, you would already have to know the name of this syntax, an inline modifier.

I find questions like this useful. Sometimes you just can't figure out what a particular piece of syntax means, and just need a pointer to the right place in the documentation. They are simple questions, but useful. I don't find a big FAQ-like wiki question helpful for this, and the documentation isn't the most clear, so this seems like exactly the kind of gap that StackOverflow is suited for filling in.

Another user disagreed, closed the question as a duplicate, and we had a discussion that got a little long for the comments, and I couldn't find a good existing discussion of this, so I decided to move the discussion here.

Is there any kind of existing policy or existing discussion that can help resolve this?

Comment: You mean it should be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28630936/what-is-mix-in-a-ruby-regular-expression? (first link on https://www.bing.com/search?q=ruby+regex+mix)... I'd downvote question if I actually know/visit Ruby tag.

Comment: If the answer to question B isn't immediately obvious from reading question A, then A and B aren't duplicates. It really is as simple as that. This wasn't a particularly helpful closure, and it's good the question was quickly re-opened.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov There we go! That's the question it should be marked duplicate of.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Why downvote? The question is perfectly fine. It is a duplicate, but duplicates happen, just marking to close as a duplicate seems perfectly fine, no need to also downvote.

Comment: @BrianCampbell reason for downvote - I know nothing about Ruby and it took me 3 seconds to find something very close to duplicate - if that is not indication of "does not show any research" I don't know what should. But "ruby" is not tag I ever visit so it may have different bar for search efforts.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That's fair. Different than my personal threshold for a downvote, but I can see your reasoning. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if the new docs feature will be able to address this.